# How to remove duplicate previews from XCode 12.2?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm a beginner in XCode and clicked on duplicate preview twice and now I can't find a way to delete the duplicates. I'm sure this is something pretty simple but I've been searching and trying everything for like an hour and can't find a solution for it...

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Already found where the problem was!
Every time duplicate preview is clicked, it adds one more view in the code.

The code below shows where my "problem" was:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

To fix this "problem", simply remove two ContentView() from the code:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good beginner question and answer, but it needs more clarity and detail. Please modify your question to be more clear that the issue was cause by your code and not the interface (include example code - not just screenshots). Then. in your answer, show the code that caused the problem so other beginners may see this and learn from it...

Comment: @Lkabo Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lkabo I think "dpascoa" is right on his point if you notice that in preview Xcode provides button with plus sign at the top to add other device so it very disturbing or even hard to think that for removing this preview instance we need todo this from code or programming side Apple team has to think again. there should be the button available in preview. by the way there is nothing wrong with dpascoa code

Answer (score 0):

[here is the Apple documentation for the above issue it is exactly the same as the answer aforementioned](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662271)

According to the documentation just delete the ContentView() you can remove the selected instance to preview

```
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

this is code is from xcode 12.4 so the slightly modify the environment

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
         
        }
    }
}
```

I personally believe Apple should think to provides the button on the top same as the other buttons there rather than moving around in the code. it wont cost them a lots. if you try the link above you can notice most of the people having this issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to add multiple Hstacks one after the other. Try addding all Hstacks inside a VStack and your error should solve. Also Make sure you have only one contentView()